# Duplicate class error when using Room for initalizing a Database

Tags: android, android-room

I started to mess around with **Room** and right now **all I did was making a dummy class with a simple Database impl for Room in Kotlin.**

So far I've got:

```
@Database(entities = [Junk::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

      companion object {

        private var appDatabaseInstance: MyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(applicationContext: Context): MyDatabase {
            if (appDatabaseInstance == null) {
                appDatabaseInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    "my_db"
                ).build()
            }
            return appDatabaseInstance!!
        }

    }
}
```

And my Junk entity is just a very **simple dummy class** for now:

```
@Entity
class Junk {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id = 0
    var name: String?=null

}
```

### Here comes the error message:

```
C:\android_projects\room_test_app\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\hu\roomtest\stuff\db\MyDatabase_Impl.java:34: error: duplicate class: hu.roomtest.stuff.db.MyDatabase_Impl
public final class MyDatabase_Impl extends MyDatabase {
             ^
```

What may cause this?

Thanks in advance.

**E D I T:**

I've added a DAO just to mess around and it says the very same for my DAO:

```
C:\android_projects\room_test_app\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\hu\roomtest\stuff\db\JunkDAO_Impl.java:34: error: duplicate class: hu.roomtest.stuff.db.JunkDAO_Impl
    public final class MyDatabase_Impl extends MyDatabase {
                 ^
```

**E D I T 2:**

Room's gradle config:

```
    def room_version = "2.5.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version"
    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

Also inside the android/defaultConfig I have this:

```
 javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
```

**E D I T 3:**

When I try to "Make Project" (CTRL F9) it says the very same error message, also with "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project".

Comment: Can you share the room gradle dependencies ?

Comment: @Zain, Thanks for the suggestion I just did it.

Comment: Thanks for that; I couldn't see something; probably it's AS hanging could you try to `Build > Clean Project` followed by `Build > Make Project`

Comment: When I try to "Make Project" it says the very same error message, also with "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project".

Comment: i will suggest change MyDatabase class name to SomethingElseDatabase.java

It will work for you.

Comment: Tried that first before wrote this post sadly not works. I'm getting mad. Why is it everything so clunky when it is coming to Android?

Comment: Can you delete the `intermediates` and `generated` folders from the `C:\android_projects\room_test_app\app\build\`

Comment: @Zain Sadly, same.

Comment: last couple of coins: remove the KSP annotation and test probably it conflicts with another room dependency; second try `def room_version = "2.5.0-beta01"`; its beta but could have a clue

Comment: @Zain Oh my god it does run without KSP annotation. But it is not an optional dependency, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after trying a couple of solutions in comments, it turns out that the KSP annotation conflicts with KAPT one; each generates its own version of the Room Database class:

```
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Both, kapt and ksp are alternative to one another; the latter is 2x faster than kapt.

[As per documentation:](https://github.com/google/ksp#kotlin-symbol-processing-api)

> Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP) is an API that you can use to develop
> lightweight compiler plugins. KSP provides a simplified compiler
> plugin API that leverages the power of Kotlin while keeping the
> learning curve at a minimum. Compared to KAPT, annotation processors
> that use KSP can run up to 2x faster.

So, you need to keep either one to solve this conflict. But notice that the ksp has some [build procedure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-quickstart.html) that you need to follow.